# Are Easter eggs derived from Ishtar Religion?

Tags: tradition, easter

Are Easter eggs derived from Ishtar religion?

And with that considered,

What now is the connection of the Easter egg to Christianity's Easter?

---

I've heard from multiple sources that the tradition of painting Easter Eggs is derived from the original practice of dipping eggs in the blood of sacrificed infants. All of this revolved around the godess Ishtar, of which the word "Easter" is derived.

Its possible that the significance of the Easter egg is a little further removed from the Ishtar-practice, in which case I'd like to know that as well. But with that considered, is there any truth to the infant sacrifice claim I hear occasionally?

I had meant to ask this in a "paganism" stackexchange, or possibly a "religion" stackexchange but could not find one. But since Easter is now so closely related to Jesus, I thought it appropriate to check the history here.

Comment: Maybe it touches slightly on the subject of the question you mention, but this question is highly targeted on the subject of the eggs and the painting of the eggs. As a side-note, I find this possible history to be a great offense on a Christian level, considering God drove out the original inhabitants of the promised land for such things (infant sacrifice). So I am seeking out the validity of this thing in particular, since Christians are inadvertently paying homage to one of the most hated practices of biblical history.

Comment: Honestly I kind of like your question better, as it is far more specific. So I'd be fine with leaving this open. But if that is where you are going with it, then instead of leaving the question open ended, you could simply as "Are Easter eggs derived from Ishtar?" By leaving it open, you could get a number of answers, including things like *"Eggs, of course, are where new life comes from. As one who has chickens, ive seen this happen."* As it is, the accepted answer at the question I linked does reference what you are asking. Thus my duplicate.

Comment: Great advice! Will make those changes. Thanks.

Comment: Do not forget that down the ages,  eggs were not eaten during Lent!

Comment: As with @Pipsqweek I find this question  to be a great offence on a Christian level, but I also find it offensive on an ethical level to repeat gossip about pagans dipping eggs in the blood of sacrificed infants.  The origin of easter eggs is nothing more sinister than a symbol of fertility (as are rabbits).  Easter occurs in spring, when all around, Christian and non-Christian alike, were celebrating the promise of a bountiful crop.

Comment: @DickHarfield This may be historical or gossip, the question is meant to find which it is (Proverbs 18:13). This claim is made from many sources. It would be nice to have a fairly comprehensive and accurate answer on it.

Comment: @KenGraham I'm honestly not sure how to take your comment after thinking about it for a while. Lent is only attested as early as the third century. Ishtar and her many forms is much older. So the only way it has not been eaten down the ages is if you are saying it is pagan in origin. Unless you are... Putting the chicken before the egg in your reasoning.

Comment: Just to clear things up, the English word **Easter** is etymologically connected to the Anglo-Saxon pagan goddes _Eostre_, cognate of the Roman _Aurora_, Greek _Eos_ and Vedic _Ushas_, but is nowise related to Semitic _Ishtar/Astaroth/Ashtoreth_.